# why readonly property setter is working objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, setter, getter, synthesize

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    NSNumber *nmbr;

}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber *nmbr;
- (NSNumber*)nmbr;
- (void)setNmbr:(NSNumber *)value;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNmbr:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
    NSLog(@"Value of number is: %@", self.nmbr);

}

- (NSNumber*)nmbr{
    return nmbr;
}

- (void)setNmbr:(NSNumber *)value{
    nmbr = value;
}

@end
```

I am expecting the program not to let setNmbr function work because nmbr property in the interface file is readonly. But it is setting the value of nmbr. What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 3):

The `readonly` doesn't prevent you from writing your own setter. It simply prevents the compiler from synthesizing a setter for you. It would be nice if it warned you if you implemented a setter for a `readonly` property, but it doesn't.

Clearly, it's inadvisable to implement a setter for a `readonly` property. Furthermore, you generally wouldn't even declare the ivar nor implement the getter for the property, either, because those would both be synthesized for you (unless you were doing something special there, which you're not).

Comment: Actually, it's not unusual to implement a setter for a readonly property, but it's normally kept private somehow.  (Making the property readonly will prevent you from assigning to the *property* -- calls to the setter must be explicit.)

Comment: Yes, but if you do that, best practice would suggest overriding the `readonly` qualifier in the private class extension. So the public interface would be `readonly` but the `@property` declaration in the private `@interface` would be `readwrite`. (Again, just like my main answer, you don't have to do this, but it's best practice, IMHO.) And, btw, if you do it this way, you don't have to manually implement the setter (unless, of course, you're doing something special that truly necessitates that) but rather private `readwrite` interface will cause it to be synthesized for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a property in objective-c, it creates 3 things for you.

1. an instance variable which you can access by using an **underscore** before the property name. Ex: `_nmbr`
2. a getter method which you can call directly by using the property name. Ex: `[self nmbr];` this will actually call `- (NSNumber *)nmbr {}` method.
3. a setter method which you can call by using a 'set' keyword before it. Ex: `[self setNmbr:@1];` this will actually call `- (void)setNmbr:(NSNumber *)nmbr {}` method.

said that, you don't need to explicitly define getters and setters. Objective-C gives you these getters and setters by default.

You are able to access the setter in the above question because you are explicitly setting them which you need not do.

Hope this helps.