# what is the getter method of a simple property called

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to understand the methods generated when properties are used.
Say I have the following declaration

```
@property int myint;
```

Now I know I could access this variables as such (say d was my instance of the class)

```
d.myint = 12; //this is equivalent to [d setMyint:12];
NSLog(@"The value is %d",d.myint); // what method is generated ?
```

What is the getter method called ? I was under the impression it was called `getMyint` however that isnt available ? Any suggestions if I might be missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getter method would be:

```
[d myInt];
```

Per the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) :

> You access or set an object’s properties via accessor methods:
>
> ```
> NSString *firstName = [somePerson firstName];
> [somePerson setFirstName:@"Johnny"]; By default, these accessor methods are synthesized automatically for you by the compiler, so you
> ```
>
> don’t need to do anything other than declare the property using
>   @property in the class interface.
>
> The synthesized methods follow specific naming conventions:
>
> The method used to access the value (the getter method) has the same
>   name as the property. The getter method for a property called
>   firstName will also be called firstName.
>
> The method used to set the value (the setter method) starts with the
>   word “set” and then uses the capitalized property name. The setter
>   method for a property called firstName will be called setFirstName:.

Comment: My pleasure. Hope it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answers, the proerty declaration gives you a *getter* and a *setter* for that instance variable for free! The notation is that you can either get `[self myInt];` or `self.myInt;`. Both calls are **100% equivalent**, i.e. they will both call the method `- (int)myInt`. This method is not visible (or rather, it's not *explicitly implemented*, see below) by default, however, you can implement it to provide some custom logic (e.g. check for specific values, error handling or lazy instantiation). If you want to override it, put this in your `.m` file.

```
- (int)myInt {
   NSLog(@"getter of my int called, current value %d", _myInt);
   return _myInt;
}
```

I only want to add to the the previous answers that in Objective-C, you have the possibility to **rename your getters and setters** when declaring the property, like so:

```
@property (getter=getMyInt) int myInt;
```

you can call those in the exact same way that you would use your normale getter:

```
int myInt = [self getMyInt];
// or
int myInt = self.getMyInt; // (will work but is not recommended since the compiler will interpret this as calling the getter of a property named `getMyInt` and only when this one is not found will actually fall back to the custom getter (thx to @NikolaiRuhe again for pointing this out))
```

**Update:**
Agreeing with most of what @NikolaiRuhe stated in his comment, here is a clarification of my answer referring to the mentioned issues:

1. This is indeed a typo, of course the way to use the *property getter* is by either calling `[self myInt]` or using dot notation `self.myInt`, and **not** `[self getMyInt]`. These calls are however 100% equivalent since they both invoke the actual getter.
2. About the *visibility*, indeed I should have been more explicit here. In OOP terms, *visibility* is a concept that describes the accessibility of *instance variables* from the outside of a particular class. I meant it exactly in the way that @NikolaiRuhe suggested, i.e. that this method is not *explicitly implemented* (so, it's not *visible in the code* by default). Sorry about this misunderstanding!
3. I am actually not sure about this point. For me this didn't make much of a difference in the past, I don't insist on this point. So I'd well acknowledge that the act of *explicitly implementing* a *getter* is not actually an *override* but rather a *replacement of the synthesized method*.
4. After explicitly renaming the getter to `getMyInt` like I suggested above, I don't see anything "*wrong*" with calling `self.getMyInt`. Why would this be the wrong way to access the property?

Comment: There are a couple of problems in this post: 1. "`[self getMyInt]` [...] will both call the method `- (int)myInt`". That's obviously wrong. 2. "This method is not visible [...]". The visibility of a method is about being private or not. You mean something like *explicitly implemented* or so. 3. "[...] you can override [the synthesized method]". The synthesized method can be *replaced*. The term "override" means something else in OOP. 4. Last example: "`self.getMyInt;`". While not producing an error, this is still the wrong way to access the property. Correct is `self.myInt`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe thanks for your response! I updated my answer. Indeed I should have been more explicit, hope this makes my points more clear! :)

Comment: reg. 3: The difference is that an *overriding* method can call the *overridden* implementation by calling to `super`. That's not possible when implementing a custom accessor. Sometimes this could be actually helpful, for example to get the synthesized implementation's atomic behavior.

Comment: reg. 4: A property is accessed by its name, not the method's name. Consider `UIView`'s `isHidden`. The property is named `hidden` and the correct way to access it using dot notation is `view.hidden`. Here the compiler uses the property's declaration to find the correct getter (`isHidden`). When using `view.isHidden` the compiler first searches for a property named `isHidden` and only when it does not find one, falls back to just sending the literal selector.

Comment: all right, thanks a lot for taking the time to clarify here as well!! I once again updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a property in objective-c, it creates 3 things for you.

- an **instance variable** which you can access by using an underscore before the property name. Ex: `_myint`
- a **getter method** which you can call directly by using the property name. Ex: `[self myint];` / `self.myint`, this will actually call `- (int)myint {}` method.
- a **setter method** which you can call by using a 'set' keyword before it. Ex: `[self setMyint:12];` / `self.myint = 12`, this will actually call `- (void)setMyint:(int)myint {}` method.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190154/why-readonly-property-setter-is-working-objective-c/29191093#29191093)

So when you write `d.myint = 12;` this is equivalent to writing `[d setMyint:12];`

And when you write `NSLog(@"The value is %d",d.myint);` this is equivalent to writing `NSLog(@"The value is %d",[d myint]);`

**Custom Getters and Setters**

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326866/2099097)

You can also give custom names to your property Getters and Setters. This is how it is done

```
@property (getter=getMyInt, setter=setMyIntWithInt) int myint;
```

Ex:

```
[d setMyIntWithInt:12]; //This will set the instance variable to 12.
NSLog(@"The value is %d",[d getMyInt]);
```

Also, you can override these methods in your implementation(.m) file for error handling or lazy instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of getter method would be-

`-(int)myint{
    return myInt;
  }`

It will return `myInt` property of the receiver if this message i.e. `d` in  your case.